# Почему не отправляются данные в ajax запросе?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Написал ajax запрос для тестирования бэка. При отправке запроса передаются только заголовки. Самих данных нет. Что может работать не праивльно?

```
function post() {
  let system = 'dbdc5f12d59f12ef1',
    keys = ['92efa55edb5', '602923fd28d6ef7b'],
    url = host + '/system/add/',
    csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

  $.ajax(url, {
    timeout: 5500,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken
    },
    data: {
      system: system,
      key: keys
    }
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    },
    function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ein забыл намекнуть Вам, что вместо

```
  data: {
      system: system,
      key: keys
  }
```

необходимо вставить:

```
data: JSON.stringify( { "system": system, "key": keys  } )
```

Comment: Как раз таки именно намекнул на это)

Comment: @Ein, намёк не был прозрачен для автора вопроса, так что я решил дополнить :)

Answer (score 3):

Когда вы указываете `"Content-Type": "application/json"` это не означает что jQuery или браузер сами сфортируют `json` из тех данных что вы передали.

Если заглянуть в консоль, то вы увидете что данные отправляются не в `json` формате:
[image]

Так же, если бек на `php`, то `$_POST` будет пуст из-за того что указан `"Content-Type": "application/json"`, даже если фактически данные не были в `json`

Такой код:

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);

var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Даст такой вывод:

```
array(0) {
}
string(73) "system=dbdc5f12d59f12ef1&key%5B%5D=92efa55edb5&key%5B%5D=602923fd28d6ef7b"
```

Comment: бэк на django. да в консели именно так. А как сформировать именно json?

Comment: @xakslim, Эмиль Сабитов дополнил мой ответ